# Pushing specific visitor ID into GA as personal identifier (Pardot)

Tags: google-analytics, pardot

I am trying to get to a point where I can identify visitors who are generating website Goals. And identifying them via their Pardot ID-s in GA.

Do you think that's possible?

On the site every visitor gets a Pardot cookie and in that there is a readable Visitor ID which via an API query can be turned into a Pardot ID.

But how can this piece of information get stitched to the rest of the GA parameters? How to push this into GA as a custom data point so I can create a report on who are the Pardot IDs that completed a certain goal this week?

Is there any guidance you can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that Pardot ID itself is not a [Personally Identifiable Information](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en) (PII) in terms of Google Analytics, there are several ways to accomplish this.

You could provide this data as [User ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662), which helps Google Analyitcs to identify users across several browsers and devices. However, this dimension is not exposed on the reporting GUI or the reporting API. (Available dimensions and metrics can be browsed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).)

Instead, or in parallel, you could store this information in a custom dimension, which, can be used in standard or custom reports, or via the reporting API as well. There a couple of things to consider. According to the [Measurement Protocoll reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_), the maximum length of this field is 150 bytes. You should also decide, if this dimension is most useful for your needs and possibilities on hit, session or user level, about which you can read [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).